# Set Keyboard Shortcuts to mean "Home" and "End"

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

While Lenovo does install some of the nicest keyboards on their ThinkPad line, I am forever frustrated by the placement of the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys. They're too far from the main keys to be useful. What I would like to do is replicate the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇠</kbd> for "Home" and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇢</kbd> for "End" that is found in macOS using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇠</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇢</kbd> respectively.

I have tried to make the change via Gnome Tweaks to no avail, and `xdotool` has also proven to be a dead-end with this particular task because it doesn't work in the applications that I use on a day to day basis. This keyboard shortcut *must* work in the following applications:

- Sublime Text
- Firefox / Edge / Chrome (one or more)

And bonus points if it works in:

- Sublime Merge
- TablePlus

While this would be awesome in Terminal, particularly when using `vi`, I don't expect these shortcuts to be used there.

Has anyone found a way to properly map keyboard shortcuts to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>?

Additional Info:

|  | Detail |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS |
| Systems | Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (2017) Lenovo ThinkPad W541 Dell XPS 13 (2016) |

Answer (score 2):

Solution found in the form of [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey)!

This can be installed from a `.deb` package or via `pip3`. I opted for the latter:

```
$ sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/autokey/autokey
```

Once installed, it can be started like so:

```
$ autokey-gtk &
```

***Note:** This application also has a QT build, which works for people using KDE Plasma, Lumina, etc.*

#### Configuration

Once AutoKey is installed, there will be a character indicator in the corner:

[image: AutoKey Indicator]

Choose "Show Main Window" to bring up the UI:

[image: AutoKey UI]

To send key commands, a new script needs to be created. This can be done by clicking the triangle beside "New", then choosing "Script". Enter any name you wish then, in the large textbox to the right, paste one of the following commands:

| Action | Command |
| --- | --- |
| Jump to beginning of current line | `keyboard.send_key("<home>")` |
| Jump to end of current line | `keyboard.send_key("<end>")` |

Next, let's set the key combination by clicking on the [Set] button next to "Hotkey":

[image: AutoKey | Set Hotkey]

This process is a little finicky, but it's possible to set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{arrow}</kbd> by doing this:

1. Click "Press to Set"
2. Press the arrow (or regular) key you wish to use (**NOT** a combination, but just the arrow or regular key)
3. Click the "Control" button
4. Click "OK"

This takes effect immediately and can be tested in just about any UI application. I have confirmed it works in:

- Sublime Text & Sublime Merge
- Firefox, Chrome, & Edge
- TablePlus
- Calibre
- `vi` and `nano`
- gEdit

Comment: Thank you so much for this Anwer