# Can I remap keys from a specific keyboard in X11?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys

I have a graphics tablet, that acts as two USB devices on Ubuntu 20.04. One pointing device and one keyboard device for the hardware buttons.
*(The tablet does not use the wacom driver, so I cannot use the usual graphics tablet utilities)*

The keyboard driver sends Shortcuts like `Ctrl-z`, and maybe also own keycodes for it. I would like to remap the buttons to other shortcuts. Is there a way to capture the keys from only one specific keyboard and remap them under X11?

Xmodmap and similar configuration files and tools seem to apply to all keyboards, but I wonder if there are options for per-device configuration. A tool that captures keys from the keyboard device and then sends the new shortcut to the active window would also be an acceptable solution for me.

I am looking for general advice that works for USB keyboards (and does not need to be tested with anything else than a standard USB keyboard). I will adapt it to my use-case myself to avoid making this question overly specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at a tool like [KeyFuzz](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/keyfuzz/), which will do exactly what you're looking for. The learning curve is a little steep at first, but with a little help from `evtest` (to find the scan and key codes for your specific keyboard), you can set up a custom remapping for *just* the one keyboard.

#### Notes:

- The latest version of KeyFuzz (0.2 as of this writing) was last updated in January 2006, but the code still compiles just fine on Ubuntu 20.04. I speak from experience on this.
- The `evtest` tool can be installed like this:

  ```
  $ sudo apt install evtest
  ```

  From there you can use it by calling the tool with `sudo`:

  ```
  $ sudo evtest
  ```

  This will give you something like:

  ```
  No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
  Available devices:
  /dev/input/event0:   Sleep Button
  /dev/input/event1:   Lid Switch
  /dev/input/event2:   Power Button
  /dev/input/event3:   AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
  /dev/input/event4:   Video Bus
  /dev/input/event5:   HDA Intel PCH Mic
  /dev/input/event6:   HDA Intel PCH Headphone
  /dev/input/event7:   HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
  /dev/input/event8:   HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
  /dev/input/event9:   HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
  /dev/input/event10:  HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
  /dev/input/event11:  HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
  /dev/input/event12:  ThinkPad Extra Buttons
  /dev/input/event13:  Integrated IR Camera: Integrate
  /dev/input/event14:  Integrated Camera: Integrated C
  /dev/input/event15:  Synaptics TM3289-002
  /dev/input/event16:  TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint
  Select the device event number [0-16]:
  ```

  Choosing a device will then print the keymap to the screen and pressing keys will then show individual details about each press:

  ```
  Event: time 1612367786.809999, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 21
  Event: time 1612367786.809999, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 33 (KEY_F), value 1
  Event: time 1612367786.809999, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
  ```

  With this, you can create your custom mapping document for KeyFuzz.

Comment: I'll look into it. Does it also stop the standard keys (e.g. ctrl-z) from being sent?

Comment: The signal is translated before it gets through the input buffer so, yes. If you map [Z] to [PgUp], then your [Ctrl]+[Z] will be seen as [Ctrl]+[PgUp] by the OS, but only for the keyboard you remap.

Comment: That's a problem. I'd like to remove, for example, the ctrl-key from one sequence, but keep it in another one. For what keyfuzz is doing I found a way to use [udev hwdb files](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/hwdb/60-keyboard.hwdb), which probably achives the same, but does not allow for changing, e.g., `ctrl-z` to a single key like just `a`. Maybe I will need a more advanced solution than just remapping keys.

Comment: To map a single key to do many things, you could [look at AutoKey](https://askubuntu.com/a/1313190/1091774). The downside is that this would apply to all keyboards, not just a specific device 

Answer (score 1):

One way to remap keys in a 1:1 manner is using udev hwdb files, like [the one shipped with systemd](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/hwdb/60-keyboard.hwdb)

This allows for matching a device and then remapping keys. It does *not* allow for remapping sequences, so `ctrl-z` can be mapped to `ctrl-a`, but not to just `a`.

Example from the linked file:

```
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnAcer*:pn*
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnGateway*:pnA0A1*:pvr*
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svneMachines:pneMachines*E725:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a5=help                                   # Fn+F1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a6=setup                                  # Fn+F2 Acer eSettings
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a7=battery                                # Fn+F3 Power Management
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a9=switchvideomode                        # Fn+F5
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b2=www
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b3=euro
 KEYBOARD_KEY_b4=dollar
```

The device IDs can for example be found using the `evtest` program, which lists all input devices. One can then use`evdev:name:My*Keyboard*Manufacturer*Model` to match input devices wit `My Keyboard Manufacturer Model`

valid key codes can be found with the command

```bsh
sed -n '/KEY_/{s/.*KEY_\([A-Za-z0-9_]\+\).*/\L\1/g;p}' /usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h | less
```

The file then needs to be installed into `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/myrules.hwdb`

So this is no full solution for the question yet, but may already help people with similar problems, who do not need a solution that can rewrite sequences of keys.