# Keyboard Shortcut for selecting text uptil the beginning of sentence

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have recently made the jump to Ubuntu from Windows and I want to bind certain shortcuts that I got used to while using Windows.
Following the answer in a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313026/set-keyboard-shortcuts-to-mean-home-and-end), I was able to bind the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> Keys to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> respectively. However, I was still not able to make use of related shortcuts such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (to select text till the beginning of the line).
Here are the Key Combinations and Expected Outcomes.

| Keyboard Shortcut | Action |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> | Select all text from the current position of the cursor to the beginning of the line |
| <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> | Select all text from the current position of the cursor to the end of the line |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> | Send the cursor to the beginning of the document. |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> | Send the cursor to the end of the document. |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> | Select all text from the current position of the cursor to the beginning of the document |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> | Select all text from the current position of the cursor to the end of the document |

It would be great if the solution could be implemented using AutoKey, but I am open to other methods too.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like these functions in Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcuts. I believe that they are left to the scope of text editors.

Emacs has some functions that you need but it uses lines not sentences.
Most Unix text editors are line based, for historical reasons.  Line and sentence are usually about of same size so you should be able to change your habits without too much pain.

Emacs and vi are programmable and covered by other sites.